# Orchard CMS 1.5 Navigation sub menus

Tags: menu, orchardcms

New to Orchard.   I have been looking for some documentation on how the menus actually work.  It appears that you can have hierarchical menus, but I cannot find any good information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Since 1.5 you can create hierarchical menus from `Navigation` admin screen. Hierarchy (and reordering) of items can easily be created by drag & drop.

Navigation screen is used to define your menus. In order to display a defined menu you need to put `Menu Widget` in the zone of your choice. When you create that widget you need to choose which menu is it going to display. Besides the choice of the menu, you can also choose some other optional parameters if you need to customize the display more (eg. display only certain level).

Comment: Can we do this from the orchard.exe?

Comment: From the `orchard.exe`, use dots within `/MenuPosition`. For instance, `/MenuPosition:1.1` is nested below `/MenuPosition:1`

Answer (score 8):

It took me a while to figure this out too. You can see how to create a navigational menu in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Sebastien-Ros-Introduces-Orchard-15) (around 8:45, but i'd recommend watching the entire video).

Basically, you need to drag & drop an item below *and to the right* of another content item in order to make a nested menu item.