# Create an Orchard CMS Submenu from the Orchard.exe Command Line

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854624/orchard-cms-1-5-navigation-sub-menus) how to create a sub-menu from the Orchard admin. Is this possible from Orchard.exe or a recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dots in the `/MenuPosition` flag.

```
menu create /MenuName:"Test Menu"

widget create MenuWidget /Title:"Test Menu Widget" /RenderTitle:false /Zone:"Navigation" /Position:"1" /Layer:"Default" /Identity:"TestMenuWidget" /MenuName:"Test Menu"

menuitem create /MenuPosition:1 /MenuText:Test1 /Url:'/' /MenuName:"Test Menu"
menuitem create /MenuPosition:1.1 /MenuText:Test1-1 /Url:'/' /MenuName:"Test Menu"
menuitem create /MenuPosition:1.2 /MenuText:Test1-2 /Url:'/' /MenuName:"Test Menu"
```